# Post file to WCF service

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have a WCF service which has a function Upload file.

```
public void UploadFile(Stream s)
{
    FileStream targetStream = null;
    Stream sourceStream = s;

    string uploadFolder = @"C:\upload\";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        //read from the input stream in 6K chunks
        //and save to output stream
        const int bufferLen = 65000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
        int count = 0;

        while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
        {
            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        targetStream.Close();
        sourceStream.Close();
    }

}


 [ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService
{
    [OperationContract]
    RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request);

    //[OperationContract]
    //void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/UploadFile")]
    void UploadFile(Stream s);
}
```

And I am using this Ajax/Jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>AJAX File Upload - Web Developer Plus Demos</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxupload.3.5.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function(){
        var btnUpload=$('#upload');
        var status=$('#status');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: 'http://localhost:35711/webservice/TransferService.svc/UploadFile',
            name: 'uploadfile',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                // if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
                //    // extension is not allowed 
                //  status.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                //  return false;
                //}
                status.text('Uploading...');
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
                //On completion clear the status
                status.text('');
                //Add uploaded file to list
                if(response==="success"){
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
                } else{
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainbody" >
        <h3>&raquo; AJAX File Upload Form Using jQuery</h3>
        <!-- Upload Button, use any id you wish-->
        <div id="upload" ><span>Upload File<span></div><span id="status" ></span>

        <ul id="files" ></ul>
</div>

</body>
```

The same function works fine when I am using ASP .Net as client. But I am not able to do it with Ajax/Jquery, Is it possible using Ajax/JQuery? and if yes then how?

Can anyone provide a simple JQuery example?

Comment: The information you have provided not enough to understand 1) add remotefile info object details tell your jquery code and what type you have used to pass the data?

Comment: I don't have Jquery for this. But yes I have edited my question and added more code to it.

Comment: Are you using jQuery file uploader?  Check this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59551/Consuming-a-WCF-ASMX-REST-Service-using-jQuery

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery you need to provider your UploadService as a REST service. In WCF this meens hosting it via webHttpBinding.

This Binding does not support MessageContracts so you have to adopt your Method signature a little bit.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUploadService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
        UriTemplate = "Uploadfile?fileName={filename}&length={length}")]
    void UploadFile(string filename, int length, Stream s);

}
```

Now you have a Url to post your file content to.

Uploadfile?fileName=Samplefile.jpg&length=72572

Comment: And how do i post it using JQuery?